# Unable to set transparency using Color.FromArgb (but Color.Transparent works)

Tags: c#, winforms

The control I want to change to his color is a ToolStripItem.
When i use this

```
 item.BackColor = Color.Black;
 item.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
```

It works as expected

[image]

But when i try this

```
item.BackColor = Color.Black;
item.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
```

or this

```
item.BackColor = Color.White;
item.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

the alpha component is like completely ignored

[image]

Any idea where the problem might have come from?

Edit : Now i know there the problem is, but i'm still unable to use transparency for text.
Some aditional informations : The item i need to change his text color is an ToolStripMenuItem. All the items needs to have a different color, so i can't just use a Renderer for my MenuStrip.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Draw the menu item text in its Paint() event. You can define a color transparency using `e.Graphics.DrawString()` (even though its practical use eludes me). About the `Color.Transparent` property: it's a Known Named color. It's primary use (for what I know, I could be wrong here) is to render the color component it's assigned to, equal to the color of a control's parent, to achieve a sort of "simulated transparency". In this case, the background color of the menu item.

Answer (score 1):

`ToolStripRenderer` uses `TextRenderer.DrawText` which uses [`WindowsGraphics.DrawText`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/misc/GDI/WindowsGraphics2.cs,201)` which uses GDI functions to draw text.

For `Color.Transparent` it doesn't render anything. For other colors GDI functions ignore the alpha part of `ARGB` color.

**What happens behind the scene?**

In the internal implementations in [`WindowsGraphics.DrawText`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/misc/GDI/WindowsGraphics2.cs,201), you can see there is a specific criteria for not drawing the text if the color is `Color.Transparent`.

So for `Color.Transparent` it doesn't draw the text:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || foreColor == Color.Transparent) 
{
    return;
}
```

About `Color.FromArgb(0,x,y,z)`, since `Color.Transparent` and `Color.FromArgb(0,x,y,z)` are not the same, so it tries to draw text when you pass `Color.FromArgb(0,x,y,z)`. It uses a [`COLORREF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449(v=vs.85).aspx) structure to pass to [`SetTextColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). you will see it always ignores the `A` value:

> When specifying an explicit RGB color, the `COLORREF` value has the following hexadecimal form:
>
> `0x00bbggrr`
>
> The low-order byte contains a value for the relative intensity of red;
>   the second byte contains a value for green; and the third byte
>   contains a value for blue. The high-order byte must be zero.

**How to draw transparent/semi-transparent text?**

If you need transparency support for drawing strings, you can override `OnRenderItemText` method of the `ToolStripRenderer` and use `Graphics.DrawString` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround, but unfortunately, it doesn't fit my needs.
The custom ToolStripRenderer needs to be applied to the MenuStrip, which made all my items are renderer the same way.
I needs to have several renderer for each item.

Another solution is to mix the ForeColor with the BackColor, to "simulate" an alpha.

Comment: About the `ToolStripRenderer`, in `OnRenderItemText`, based on having alpha in fore-color, you can decide to call `base.OnRenderItemText` method or use any other solution including `DrawString`.

Comment: Anyway, I believe the post answers the question you asked: *Any idea where the problem might have come from?*

Comment: You right, that's why i upvoted him. But my problem is not resolved and i will not create another question for that

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So you may want to change your question, because you are asking just for the reason: *Any idea where the problem might have come from?* You may want to edit the question and add the expected behavior based on the specific input.